# Pm2 Ubuntu Discord Bot Not running: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, discord.js, hosting, pm2

I have recently setup my server (unbuntu 22.04) with nodejs and pm2 to run my discord bot. Whenever I try to run pm2 start I get the error below, I did not get this error before.

pm2 5.3

djs 14.11

```js
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:101:39)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/ObjectionerBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js:6:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
/root/ObjectionerBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:29
        userAgentAppendix: options.rest?.userAgentAppendix
                                        ^
```

This is the file locations:

[image]

This is my index file (Pm2 runs this I believe):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { Client, Collection, Events, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder, SlashCommandBuilder, Partials  } = require('discord.js');
const { token, incoming_messages } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers] });

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}


client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {

      let welcome = Math.floor(Math.random() * incoming_messages.length)

      

      let NewMem = incoming_messages[welcome].replace("${member}", member)

      const E = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("**New Member**")
        .setDescription(NewMem)
        .setColor("#A020F0")
        .setTimestamp()
      
      console.log("MEMBER JOINED")
      member.roles.add([`951942010309345311`])
client.channels.cache.get("952666424436994078").send({ embeds: [E] });
});

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('System is yes!');
  const I = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(`#0a9239`)
    .setTitle("**RESTART**")
    .setDescription(`The bot has restarted, this is normal or a update.`)
    .setTimestamp()

  

    client.channels.cache.get("952958463317794826").send({ embeds: [I] });
    client.user.setActivity("objectionstudios.com");
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

  if (!command) return;

  try {
    await command.execute(interaction, client);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
  }
});

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, interaction => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
    console.log(interaction.id)
 
  }
});


client.login(token);
```

If there is more relevant information that I can add please inform me.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Without any code its hard to tell what might be wrong.

Comment: I can provide my bots index file if you like but before I moved to the server it worked fine?

Comment: Discord.JS requires NodeJS 16 or higher, you seem to be running lower than 14 due to the optional chaining operator (`?.`) not being recognized. Update NodeJS

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it was running node version 12????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As elitezen said, my node was outdated running v12 instead of v16+.

I followed this guide to update my node since ubuntu linux contains an outdated version: https://blog.hubspot.com/website/update-node-js

I fixed this by updating it and restarting the process.